# Magento 2 - Argument 2 missing error on overriding file

Tags: magento2, category, blocks, overrides

I am trying to override `Magento\Catalog\Block\Category\View`

added this code in di.xml

```
<preference for="Magento\Catalog\Block\Category\View" type="Naheed\AllProducts\Block\Category\View" />
```

And my new file is this Vendor\Module\Block\Category\View

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Category;

/**
 * Class View
 * @api
 * @package Magento\Catalog\Block\Category
 * @since 100.0.2
 */
class View extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Category\View
{
    /**
     * Core registry
     *
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Registry
     */
    protected $_coreRegistry = null;

    /**
     * Catalog layer
     *
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer
     */
    protected $_catalogLayer;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Category
     */
    protected $_categoryHelper;

    protected $priceHelper;

    protected $_storeManager;

    protected $categoryRepository;

    protected $_request;

    protected $productFactory;

    protected $eavconfig;   
    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Resolver $layerResolver
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Category $categoryHelper
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Resolver $layerResolver,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Category $categoryHelper,
        \Magento\Framework\Pricing\Helper\Data $priceHelper,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryRepository $categoryRepository,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\ProductFactory $productFactory,
        \Magento\Eav\Model\Config $eavconfig,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_categoryHelper = $categoryHelper;
        $this->priceHelper = $priceHelper;
        $this->_catalogLayer = $layerResolver->get();
        $this->_coreRegistry = $registry;
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->_request = $request;
        $this->categoryRepository = $categoryRepository;
        $this->productFactory = $productFactory;

        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    ...
}
```

Now I am getting error Argument 2 passed in __constructor

Comment: why you need class rewrite? Please explain your purpose.

Comment: update error log

Comment: @AmitBera I need to hide some filters for specific categories. Do my purpose linked with the error I have mentioned? I mean magento give me option to override any file and it does not require any purpose :D

Comment: Actually my main concern is, I am unable to override `Magento\Catalog\Block\Category\View` file

Comment: @AhmedZameer please delete generated folder,try again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to changes the

> ```
> parent::__construct($context, $data);
> ```

**to**

> ```
> parent::__construct($context, $layerResolver, $registry, $categoryHelper, $data);
> ```

The original method  `Magento\Catalog\Block\Category\View::__construct(`

the definition has 5 parameter,

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Resolver $layerResolver,
    \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
    \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Category $categoryHelper,
    array $data = []
) {
```

So you have your class **method** `__construct(` must provide this 5 parameter. This is basically the oops concept

Comment: Thanks Amit, I will apply this. Will get back to you :)

Comment: Note that after this  changes you must need di compile properly.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks :)